# What's שולי הקדירה?

Tags: translation

The משנה ברורה הלכות שבת סימן רנ״ג (מ״ו) talks about שולי הקדירה. What exactly is that talking about? Is it the top of the pot or the bottom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom of the pot: the word שול denotes the bottom part of a vessel, garment or animal. So, for example, the skirts of a robe or the bottom-most rim of a cauldron. You can see Jastrow (s.v. שול) for examples. In this instance, the Mishna Berurah is speaking of a pot that is placed in such a fashion that the bottom part of it is coming into contact with lit coals. This would include pots that are put on top of coals, obviously, as well as ones that are merely touching them from the side.